# The -t option of ffplay won't stop playback

Tags: ffmpeg

Just getting started with ffmpeg and ffplay. I do this: 
ffplay -t 5 somesong.mp3 
and it gets to about 5 seconds and then just starts making a clicking noise?

I'm using the latest version I just downloaded from their site.

(Windows 7 64-bit)

Answer (score 20):

To make `ffplay` exit automatically when the maximum duration is reached you need to use the `autoexit` option, otherwise it just cuts the input and waits:

`ffplay -autoexit -t 5 somesong.mp3`

Comment: How to stop it immediately, effectively terminating the process via some command flag?

Comment: @Henrik You either terminate the process or send the `quit` [interactive command](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html#While-playing).

Comment: I'm a bit stupid, but, how do you issue an interactive command? Is that when you press a key (such as Esc in this case)? Or can you issue it from another Cmd window such as `ffplay -q` or something?

Comment: Thanks, aergistal. But how is that done? (You don't have to write a lot of code, just point me in the right direction what we're dealing with. I'm no coder, so I don't know if giving instructions to processes' ´stdin´ means writing a short command/oneliner, or a fullblown script. :) )

Comment: @Henrik you would need some form of script, for example in Python there's [Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)